# Decrypting RSA encoded message in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, primes

As an IT teacher I would like to show my students how the RSA algorithm works. I would also like to show them that 'hacking' it by iterating over all possible primes takes forever.

Encrypting and decrypting works perfectly fine for primes < 1000. When I execute the same algorithm with slightly larger primes, the decryption result is wrong.

```
Eg:
p, q are primes  
n = p * q  
phi = (p-1) * (q -1)  
d = (1 + (k * phi)) / e;  
**encryption:**  
c = (msg ^ e) % n  
**decryption**  
message = c ^ d % n;
```

For p = 563 and q = 569 the decryption works fine.
For p = 1009 and q = 1013 on the other hand, the decrypted message =/= the original message.

I think the error is in the calculation of private exponent "d". I replaced all int's by BigIntegers, but it doesn't change a thing. Does anyone have an idea?

```
class RSA
{
    private BigInteger primeOne;
    private BigInteger primeTwo;
    private BigInteger exp;
    private BigInteger phi;
    private BigInteger n;
    private BigInteger d;
    private BigInteger k;


    private void calculateParameters(){
        // First part of public key:
        this.n = this.primeOne * this.primeTwo;
        // Finding other part of public key.
        this.phi = (this.primeOne - 1) * (this.primeTwo - 1);
        //Some integer k
        this.k = 2;
        this.exp = 2;

        while (this.exp < (int) this.phi)
        {
            // e must be co-prime to phi and
            // smaller than phi.

            if (gcd(exp, phi) == 1)
                break;
            else
                this.exp++;
        }

        this.d = (BigInteger) (1 + (this.k * this.phi)) / this.exp; ;
    }

    // Return greatest common divisors
    private static BigInteger gcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
    {
        if (a == 0)
            return b;
        return gcd(b % a, a);
    }

    //Encryption algorithm RSA
    public string Encrypt(string msg)
    {
        calculateParameters();
        BigInteger encryptedNumber = BigInteger.Pow(BigInteger.Parse(msg),(int) this.exp) % this.n;
        // Encryption c = (msg ^ e) % n
        return Convert.ToString(encryptedNumber);

    }

    public string Decrypt(string encrypted)
    {

        BigInteger intAlphaNumber = BigInteger.Parse(encrypted);
        BigInteger decryptedAlphaNumber = BigInteger.Pow(intAlphaNumber,(int) this.d) % n;
        return Convert.ToString(decryptedAlphaNumber);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is BigInteger.Parse(msg) doing what you expect?  What if the message alphanumeric?

Comment: You always have k=2 in your implementation.  So in short, your heuristic for computing d will not always work.

Comment: In my original code I transform letters to numbers, but I kept that out. I only want to encrypt the number 89 ( = "HI"). When I encrypt it with large primes, the number gets decrypted wrongly.

Comment: When n>2^16, you need to worry about overflow in a 32-bit int.

Comment: You probably want to use ModPow instead of Pow and Mod individually. It scales much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the math.

Recall `e*d == 1 mod phi(n)`, which implies `e*d = 1 + k*phi(n)`.  In your implementation, you assume that `k` is always going to be 2.  That assumption is wrong.

For proof, consider your erroneous case of `p` = 1009 and `q` = 1013.  In this case, `exp` is 5 according to your algorithm for choosing it.  The corresponding correct value of `k` is 4 so `d` should be 816077.  However, your algorithm erroneous computes `d` as 408038.

If you put an assertion in your code to check that `exp*d = 1 + k*phi(n)`, then you will readily see when your heuristic for `k` works and when it does not.

Use the extended Euclidean algorithm to get the right solution for `d`.

### Also:

"I would also like to show them that 'hacking' it by iterating over all possible primes takes forever."  Good to let them hack, and once they get frustrated and realise that it is not going to work, then you can show them that a little mathematics could have proven that to them in advance.  The [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) shows us the density of prime numbers.  You could take for example primes on the order of 2^1024 and show them that there are on the order of 2^1014.5 primes this size.  Then ask them how many tries can they do per second, and compute the number of years it would take them to crack via this naive method (or you can take the approach of looking at the storage for a table of all primes).  And then that can lead into better solutions like the number field sieve.  Oh so much fun!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was very stupid of me... Thank you very much for the idea, I will certainly have a look into the theorem!

Now it works with

```
private static BigInteger ModInverse(BigInteger a, BigInteger n)
    {
        BigInteger t = 0, nt = 1, r = n, nr = a;

        if (n < 0)
        {
            n = -n;
        }

        if (a < 0)
        {
            a = n - (-a % n);
        }

        while (nr != 0)
        {
            var quot = r / nr;

            var tmp = nt; nt = t - quot * nt; t = tmp;
            tmp = nr; nr = r - quot * nr; r = tmp;
        }

        if (r > 1) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(a) + " is not convertible.");
        if (t < 0) t = t + n;
        return t;
    }
```